# Visual Studio 2015 Toolbox item/s Disable (Grey)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, toolbox

I am using Visual Studio 2015 , and some of ToolBox items are unclickable/disable/grey. How can i solve it?

Thank you.

Here is screenshot of the toolbox

[image: ToolBox]

Comment: Yeap, if you look closely some of them white. (For.Ex ImageList) Active.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the toolbox and uncheck the option that reads "Show All".

Comment: I need to use ImageButton.

Comment: @CanUzun For a winforms project?